# Displaying text column in an Excel Pivot Table as in place of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I have a table which is a bit like this

```
NAME     | ROLE   | AUDIT CHECKED?
Person A | Admin  | Yes
Person B | User   | Maybe
Person C | SupUser| No
Person A | User   | Yes
Person A | SupUser| Yes
```

I am trying to output a report with the person's name on the y-axis and the roles the person have assigned to them on the x-axis, with the intersection being if the person has been audit checked to display yes/no/maybe, but Excel seems to be expecting only values on the table itself.

My current solution involves putting Audit Checked? as the value field, then filtering the table by Audit Checked? and coloring in the cells with values in them via conditional formatting, in different colors depending on what Audit Checked? setting I have on. But I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this so I don't have to recompute my table everytime there is an update to the data?

Comment: See here: https://youtu.be/wslp2BqHuz8